# Why is Visual Studio 2017 hanging when I delete a folder?

Tags: visual-studio

I updated 2 hours ago. My mistake. Everything always fucks up whenever I update anything...

Now I'm sit here waiting almost 20 minutes for Visual Studio to remove a particular folder from the Solution Explorer while it sporadically stops responding and recovering.

Never had this issue before the update so what am I supposed to do now?

Comment: Have you tried to restart Windows?

Comment: No. Shockingly I'd hoped to avoid a course of action that would take a further 90 minutes of my day to complete.

Comment: Well, VS update contains most of the time shared components, that won't be replaced until restart. You might not encounter the effect of not performing such final tasks - now you have. Sorry to say, but you will most likely waste much more than those 90 minutes if you stick to not restarting.